# Generate an evenly spaced point grid

Tags: c++, algorithm

I currently have an algorithm that generates a point grid. It takes input from the user in the form of a length of x (`lx`) and a length of y (`ly`), and what increment, or delta, (`dx` and `dy`) to space the points by. I need the points to **always start and finish on the edges** of the bounding square defined by `lx` and `ly`. I've tried a few methods:

The start edge of the bounding square is defined as:

```
double startx = lx / -2.0, starty = ly / -2.0;
```

---

My first method determines the number of points and rounds:

```
int numintervalx = round(lx / dx), numintervaly = round(ly / dy);
```

---

My second method determines the number of points and uses the closest integer greater than the number of points:

```
int numintervalx = ceil(lx / dx), numintervaly = ceil(ly / dy);
```

---

My third method determines the number of points and uses the closest integer less than the number of points:

```
int numintervalx = floor(lx / dx), numintervaly = floor(ly / dy);
```

---

The delta is then recalculated to fit the bounding box:

```
dx = lx / double(numintervalx);
dy = ly / double(numintervaly);
```

---

These are then fed into a `for` loop that generates the points themselves:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= numintervaly; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j <= numintervalx; j++)
  {
    double point[3] = {startx + dx * j, starty + dy * i, 0};
  }
```

---

Is there another, more accurate, method that would make the actual grid closer to the user specified grid that still always starts and finishes on the edges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the integer conversion as adding error.  In that case, the way to minimize the error added when converting to an integer is rounding.  The worst case is if the user inputs values such that lx/dx is something.5, which means a rounding error of 0.5.  Given your problem, this is the best you can do.

Consider renaming numpoints to numintervals or something, as you actually create one more point than numpoints, which is strange.

Comment: Good point about the naming. I also think you've made a good point that the user is just going to have to accept the error if he/she decides to use non-optimal generation values.

Answer (score 0):

Require the users to give you values of `lx` and `ly` that are multiples of `dx` and `dy`, respectively. This will, of course, require some basic input validation, but it will guarantee the actual grid will be exactly the same as the user-specified grid, with points always starting and finishing on the edges.

Answer (score 0):

your input is obviously not guaranteed to be compatible with `lx` being an integer multiple of `dx`, hence your problems. You *must* therefore require inputs that are compatible, ideally by taking `nx` as input and either `dx` or `lx`, whatever makes more sense in your application.

Alternatively, you can treat the user input as guide only, i.e. take

```
nx = int(ceil(lx/dx));    // get suitable number of points
dx = lx/nx;               // set suitable spacing to fit range exactly
```

Comment: The number of points is irrelevant. Its the *density* that is important.

Comment: @Drise well, see my edit --- just realised that this is actually one of your own options ...

Comment: @Drise why are you not satisfied with it?

Comment: Generating a grid with `lx = ly = 2` and `dx = dy = .85` produces a relatively large error and possible unwanted behavior and could frustrate the user.

Comment: Right.  It does produce large error. It might frustrate the user.  Within the bounds of your problem statement, there's nothing to be done about it without changing the rules of math.  Document it and move on, or change the problem by choosing a better interface or validating the input.

Comment: In which sense does it produce a large error? You must make *sensible* requirements. Either you want the density error to be small *or* the boundaries to match exactly, but *not both*!

Comment: @Walter The delta gets adjusted to either 1.0 or 0.66666, neither of which are close at all to 0.85.

Comment: There's a communication problem here.  What this amounts to is that what you are dissatisfied with is your own problem statement, and we can't help you with that.  You say: "user may input any lx and dx.  Internally, I must have lx/dx = integer.  So I adjust dx.  Now I'm not happy with dx."  Your choices are few.  Adjust lx instead.  Or limit the input.  Please explain what sort of help you'd like with this, or where the communication is failing.

Comment: @Peter I can't limit the input, or adjust `lx`. So my only alternative  is to adjust `dx`, but I was trying to come up with a ... more elegant solution to adjust `dx`.